# UIPickerView display issue

Tags: ios, swift3, uipickerview, ios11

In iOS 11 I've a display problem with a `UIPickerView`.

I've a view that I move up and down when the keyboard appears or disappears. I, sometime, not all the time, have the problem that the `UIPickerView` doesn't show anything in it.

The item is still selected, I'm able to access it when I save, but the `UIPickerView`is totally empty, nothing is shown.

Is it a known issue? 
Am I doing something wrong?
What can I do?

Here is how I move the view:

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0{   
        if actionName.isEditing {
            self.view.frame.origin.y -= 398
        } 
    // Other code but same way
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Eureka for form building: https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka

Another note is that there are now keyboards which have different heights. For instance keyboard where you can draw characters. It doesn't have the same height as default one. Also if users disable/enable recommendations.

Comment: At first I was using `if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue` but since the last update to iOS11 and Xcode9 it often return `0`... So... I can't use it now... 

I'll check Eureka, thanks.